# How to remove weird outline inside textarea element on focus

Tags: html, css

I need to remove these 2 black lines on the top and bottom of the textarea element.
It only shows up when the height of the element is smaller than the content inside it/the scroll bar shows up.

No focus/normal element
[image]

Normal outline on focus for my text area element(What I want)
[image]

This is what shows up if the height is too small/scroll bar shows up
[image]

When content is bigger than height
[image]

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
.f-input {
    color:#333333;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: 0px solid grey;
    font-size: 14px;
    height:38px;
    line-height: 26px;
}
.f-input:focus{
    outline-style: solid;
    border:2px solid var(--primary);
    outline:none !important;
}
```

--primary is green

Comment: I think its a rendering issue since none of the suggestions are working

Answer (score 0):

You can try something this to remove text area outline:

```
textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

*Update: about textarea height*
You might want to play with [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) about textarea attribute: rows

*Example using CSS:*

```css
/*
textarea:invalid {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

textarea:valid {
   border: 2px solid lime;
}
*/
textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web devel

opment technologies.
</textarea>
```

*Example using JS:*

```js
document.getElementById("custom").style.outline = "none";
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>

<textarea id="custom" rows="4" cols="50">
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>
```

Comment: Don't need to do anything about height, I just want to remove the weird outline, I have uploaded the code for it. Outline:none doesn't fix it.

Comment: @BaekhanSung do you see any other rule overwriting it? also test on inspect element with !important like: textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for !important. I have already tried that as well, ill keep looking in inspect element for anything else.

Comment: also try: 
textarea:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

```css
textarea {
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
overflow-y: auto; /* change to scroll after content height bigger than textarea height */
resize: vertical;
}

textarea::focus {
outline: none !important;
/* outline options
outline-width: 1px;
outline-style: dashed;
outline-color: red; 
*/
border-right: 1px solid black;
border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="write something ..."></textarea>
```